# Использование case when then в условии запроса

Tags: sql, oracle

Здравствуйте. Вот условие моего запроса, блок where:

```
WHERE SPR.NTD_NAME = :n and DIAM = :d and THICKNESS_FROM <= :t;
```

Мне нужно проверить ещё одно поле на null, и если оно не null тогда тоже добавить по нему условие. Попробовал реализовать это примерно так, но не работает:

```
WHERE SPR.NTD_NAME = :n and DIAM = :d and THICKNESS_FROM <= :t  and case when THICKNESS_TO is not null then THICKNESS_TO > :t end;
```

Что я делаю не так? И как можно сделать то что я хочу.

Comment: после then нельзя ставить условие

Comment: @nick_n_a, как тогда можно сделать то что мне требуется?

Comment: `case when THICKNESS_TO is not null then THICKNESS_TO > :t end` не верно, `THICKNESS_TO > :t` вносите в условную часть, а остаток наружу допустим так `case when THICKNESS_TO is not null and THICKNESS_TO > :t then 1 end = 1`

Comment: @nick_n_a, это я уже понял, как это должно выглядеть правильно? Можете подсказать?

Comment: @nick_n_a, а можно чуть поподробней? Что такое условная часть или как это будет выглядеть можете пример привести?

Comment: @nick_n_a в вашем примере как я понял если THICKNESS_TO, null, тогда ему присвоена единица?

Comment: `(THICKNESS_TO is null OR THICKNESS_TO > :t)`

Comment: @Mike благодарю, как всегда выручаете. Если не сложно можете оформить как ответ и я приму его. Спасибо ещё раз.

Comment: @Андрей там Dmirty уже поправил ответ.

Comment: @Mike да, всё вижу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто воспользуйтесь операцией `or` вместо хитростей с `case`:

```
WHERE SPR.NTD_NAME = :n 
  and DIAM = :d 
  and THICKNESS_FROM <= :t  
  and (THICKNESS_TO is null or THICKNESS_TO > :t);
```

Comment: Dmitry, проблема в том что в таком случае мне вообще не выдаст выборку если THICKNESS_TO всё таки будет null, а мне нужно что бы если оно null тогда выдало те строке в которых THICKNESS_FROM <= :t, как то так.

Comment: Да, я понял уже. Сейчас перепишу.

Answer (score 1):

1. Хочу отметить, что запись `case when условие then выражение  [else выражение  ] end` не разрешает в выражение ставить условие.  Вместо этого условие нужно прибавить в условие, а в then написать например 1, тогда case будет возвращать 1 при правильном выражении. Может это громоздко, но можно записать так `case when THICKNESS_TO is not null and THICKNESS_TO > :t then 1 else 0 end = 1`
2. Очень часто приходится сталкиваться с null. Во многих версиях sql есть функции  `COALESCE`*,  `NVL` (Oracle, Informix)  `ISNULL` (MSSQL)которая выбирает первый аргумент если он не null, иначе второй аргумент. Для даного случая можно выкрутится так:

   ```
   WHERE SPR.NTD_NAME = :n 
    and DIAM = :d 
    and THICKNESS_FROM <= :t  
    and NVL(THICKNESS_TO, :t+1) > :t; /*NVL(THICKNESS_TO, 0) > :t */
   ```

Т.е. если THICKNESS_TO не задано, используется `:t+1` (или поставить большое число, как костыль). Если это записать через `case when` то это будет так:  `and case when THICKNESS_TO is null then 0 else THICKNESS_TO end >  :t`

*COALESCE - есть почти во всех версиях SQL, точно есть в Firebird,MSSQL,Oracle,Informix.

Comment: вряд ли `nvl(X, 0) > :t` даст желаемый результат если :t положительное число, придется делать какое то заведомо большое число. И кстати, я бы немного по другому написал про эти функции. дело в том, что coalesce функция из стандартов SQL и есть во всех СУБД (в oracle с 9 версии), а nvl и isnull только чуть более короткая запись в конкретных СУБД. поэтому на SO я предпочитаю ставить акценты на coalesce как на наиболее универсальную

Comment: Mike, вы правы запись с nvl не подойдёт, либо придётся сделать костыль поставив очень большое число.

Comment: Да... недосмотрел. Сам часто isnull использую.

Comment: @nick_n_a вы так и не поправили определение coalesce как Mike предложил, наверное забыли.

Comment: @0xdb я поставил t+1 вместо большого числа.

Comment: @nick_n_a  я имел ввиду следующее предложение - COALESCE (Firebird) неверно.

Comment: @0xdb поправил.

Comment: @nick_n_a Хмм, более полгода прошло. Понимаю, занятость на работе. Но более одного раза голосовать не могу ;)

Comment: Я сначала подумал что  "COALESCE (Firebird) неверно" - это что Firebird не умеет COALESCE, я и подумал что странное замечание.

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример

```
select trunc(sysdate) from dual 
where 1=:a and (case when 1 > :c then 1 else 2 end) > :b;
```

где `a = 1`, `b = 0`, `c = 0`

В последнем условии, в `then 1 else 2 end`, можно `else` опустить.